# How to add an extra item to POWER SHUTDOWN "Device Options" list on Samsung S3?

Tags: android, events, broadcastreceiver, android-button, android-event

I need to add an extra option to the spinner list that gets poped up when the power button is long pressed on S3. The list already has the following items -

1. Power Off
2. Airplane Mode
3. Restart
4. Mute - Vibrate - Sound
5. ***Need to add my new option here.***

How to add my option to this list? I read through the Intent and and [ACTION_SHUTDOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) documentation. But this broadcast is fired after the POWER OFF is already chosen by the user. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do is get this?

Step #1: Download the source code to Android.

Step #2: Modify that source code to include your app and put your app in the power-down menu.

Step #3: Build your revised edition of Android into a ROM mod.

Step #4: Install that ROM mod on whatever device you can. Whether you can do this on a Galaxy S III, I cannot say.

It is not possible for you to modify this menu from an ordinary SDK application.

Comment: Thanks Commonsware. Can you point me to any resource which can guide me through the process of getting the android source, adding my app to android source and building a ROM? Thanks

Comment: Actually, you won't need to build the whole Android system. The UI and logic for the dialog are placed in the `framework-res.apk` just like in a normal Android app. See for example [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1406207). - As CommonsWare noted, your task cannot be achieved from a normal application.

Comment: Changed the link to another one with more detailed informations.

Comment: Oh, by the way, note that I already [failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901159/emulator-breaking-framework-res-apk) to do this :)

Comment: Can we do something in our app on the long press of Power Button ?
Can I make a broadcast receiver for that ?